# IS it possible to find specific Hyperlink within VBox in javafx?

Tags: java, hyperlink, javafx, vbox

Is it possible to find a specific Hyperlink within VBox container?

Say i have code that dymanically adds hyperlinks into a VBox element but i dont want to add the same link twice, easiest way here any ideas?

What i thought of was to search and see if the Hyperlink already is within the VBox by doing something like:

```
myContainer.getChildren().forEach(node -> {
    if(node.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Hyperlink") {
          Node n = node.getClass();
          // Do my stuff
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code compares the class name (without the package), so you cannot distinguish the various hyperlinks that way.
What you can do is assign each `Hyperlink` an ID that is based on the URL:

```
String url = ...
String urlToID = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
...
// check if that urlToID is already present
boolean present = false;
for (Node child : myContainer.getChildren()) {
  if (child.getId().equals(urlToID)) {
    present = true;
    break;
}
if (!present) {
  Hyperlink link = ...
  link.setId(urlToID);
  myContainer.getChildren().add(link);
}
```

The for loop can be further optimized using streams, but I think this is more readable:

```
boolean present = myContainer.getChildren().stream().filter(node -> 
                      return node.getId().equals(urlToId);)
                  .findFirst().isPresent();
```

Comment: Thanks, how can it be more optimized?

Comment: I added the version to initialize `present` with streams.